# no other git errors except "failed to repack" and I'm a git noob

Tags: git

I tried to run garbage collection in our master git repository, and it said "error: failed to run repack" but I have not seen any other error messages to help me determine the problem. "git fsck" and "git fsck --strict" both finish happily without errors but "git gc" and "git gc --agressive" both end with:

```
%> git gc
Counting objects: 120867, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58692/58692), done.
error: failed to run repack 57/120867)
```

There is plenty of memory and disk space. We are using git 1.7.11

I am not very git knowledgeable, but other questions with this problem seem to have a particular file that gets mentioned and needs to be manually repaired. I see no other errors and don't know how to proceed to repair this and would appreciate any help, possibly using small words with explanation or pointers to git topics if it gets complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, and maybe this will help somebody else.

I eventually set GIT_TRACE=1 and ran "git gc", and the last command it ran before the only error was:

```
trace: built-in: git 'pack-objects' '--keep-true-parents' '--honor-pack-keep' '--non-empty' '--all' '--reflog' '--unpack-unreachable=2.weeks.ago' '--local' '--delta-base-offset' '/db/sds14/user2/cwolf/cg_sandbox/.git/objects/pack/.tmp-24230-pack'
```

Running that command manually shed some light on the actual error:

```
%> git 'pack-objects' '--keep-true-parents' '--honor-pack-keep' '--non-empty' '--all' '--reflog' '--unpack-unreachable=2.weeks.ago' '--local' '--delta-base-offset' '/db/sds14/user2/cwolf/cg_sandbox/.git/objects/pack/.tmp-24230-pack'
Counting objects: 120986, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58821/58821), done.
Filesize limit exceeded
```

"unlimit filesize" was all it took to get "git gc" to work again. I don't know why this system error was hidden from me when run the other way.

Comment: linux SuSE, using a csh login shell. for a bash shell the unlimit command is 'limit -f unlimited' and I don't think the issue exists on non-unix hosts.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation with just "failed to run repack" (overwriting the "Counting objects (#/#)") and no other error message; in my case, all it took was using the `--aggressive` option to make `git gc` work (though it still failed afterward without that option)

This was on Windows 10; git version 2.19.0.windows.1

Comment: I'm having the same problem with git version 2.19.1.windows.1 in Windows 10. The --agressive works but does not work without it. I am tried git gc when I started getting repack errors pushing to remote repositories so now I suspect the problem may be with my local repository.

    git gc --agressive